A short story with a Gaelic Irish sorceress who turns two Irish-English men into dogs
I read this fantasy short story at least 30 years ago, in a collection in French, but it is certainly a translation from English, because it takes place in Ireland. From the context, before independence, probably in the second half of the 19th century, not much earlier than that.
There are two scions of English families who centuries earlier got big estates in Ireland. With time, all the real estate has been sold, but the two guys have still enough money not to have to work and to spend their time criss-crossing Ireland to hunt and fish, but only in small villages where the taverns are cheap enough, and dirt-poor people treat with respect people with money like they still have.
They are supposed to meet in one such village. When the main character arrives, the landlady of the tavern tells him that his friend has arrived, has left all his things in the room he had rented, and has gone out for a walk, but has not yet come back.
The next day, the friend is not yet back. The main character goes for a walk to see the picturesque area. In particular there is a dilapidated tower on a hill nearby. During his walk a very beautiful woman on a horse rides past him, going in the direction of the tower, followed by a shaggy dog. (No, this is not a "shaggy dog story"; I am back-translating my memory of the description of the dog, and the word that came to my mind is "shaggy", but I don't remember the exact wording in French).
Back at the tavern the friend is still not back. The main character describes the woman. The landlady says she was "La Dame de XXX", which might be a translation of "Lady  XXX" or "Dame XXX", hard to tell from the French.  I realised immediately from her attitude she did not mean a "normal" woman, but some uncanny apparition, a ghost or a fay. But the man does not understand that. He does, however, realise that "XXX" is a typical Gaelic name. Fascinated by the beauty of the woman, he decides to go to the tower, hoping she was living in some inhabitable part at the bottom of the tower.
And indeed, when he reaches the tower and knocks at the door the woman opens and invites him in. The shaggy dog immediately seems to attack him, barking very loud, but the woman casts it out. She offers her guest a drink, maybe some food. IIRC, she does not offer him "le reste", as a well-educated Frenchman would say, to the guest's disappointment.
Something in the drink or the food makes him fall asleep. When he starts to wake up, still dazed, he hears his friends telling him "Idiot, why did you stay? I tried to warn you, I barked as loud as I could". At this point he wakes up completely and sees that he is also now a dog.

In Gaelic the word for woman fairy/fey/little people is "Bean-sidhe" (pronounced ban-shee), from which we get the word banshee for a wailing/shrieking ghost. There's also Leannan (also Leanan) sidhe, which means "fairy/fey lover", which is associated with witchcraft, so might be a help. Perhaps "Lady Leannan" or "Lady Leanan" might get somewhere.

@bob1  Thnaks but no, that would have been too obvious, even this besotted man would have understood. It was some family name that looked Englsish or ratehr Anglo-saxon to me, but probably recognisably as Gaelic to someone living there. No prefix like O' or Mac. I looked in the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_name  and names like Brennan, Collins, Griffith, Higgins, Mellows, Pearce, Forbes, Conry, Walsh, Greene, Cullen, Ross, Ryan, Burgess, Mooney would fit with my memory : mentioned as typical Irish (in Anglicized form) but I would not be able to tell.

@bob I could add Joyce but that would have registered in my memory. Higgins too, when i think about it. (My Fair Lady..) Probably not Burgess, either.

I know this one, and I'm hopeful that I have it an anthology at home. Will look it up for you later!

@VinceBowdren Thanks in advance !

I believe this is John Collier's The Lady on the Grey, printed in the New Yorker in 1951.
It opens with:

Ringwood was the last of an Anglo-Irish family that had played the devil in County Clare for three centuries. At last the family estates vanished and Ringwood lived on a few hundred a year of his own. He and his friend, Bates, the same sort of man, roamed around the countryside hunting and pursuing young women. One day Ringwood followed Bates to a village called Knockderry. He saw a beautiful girl driving cows along the road. He was about to go after her when an even more beautiful young woman went by on a horse. He immediately set about pursuing her. The pursuit was easy. She invited him into her house although her dog whined and tried to prevent it.

and ends with:

Don't, for Heaven's sake" said Bates in his altered voice. Don't yell. She'll thrash us if you do."
"What's that?" said Ringwood. "Thrash us? What the hell are you talking about?"
At that moment a log rolled on the hearth, and a little flicker sprang up, and he saw his long and hairy forelegs, and he knew.

A great story!

A great story indeed !
